# How do I parse a currency value as *big.Int in Go?

Tags: go, parsing, currency, biginteger

I want to parse a string like "12.49" into a `*big.Int` in Go. The resulting `*big.Int` should represent the amount of cents in the given value, in this case 1249. Here are some more examples of inputs and their expected outputs:

- "3": 300
- "3.1": 310
- ".19": 19

I already tried working with `*big.Float` and [its `Int` function](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.Int), but realized, that `*big.Float` does not provide arbitrary precision.

Right now I'm using this algorithm, but it seems fragile ([Go Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/JMXujql8iJP)):

```
func eurToCents(in string) *big.Int {
    missingZerosUntilCents := 2
    i := strings.Index(in, ".")
    if i > -1 {
        missingZerosUntilCents -= len(in) - i - 1
        if missingZerosUntilCents < 0 {
            panic("too many decimal places")
        }
    }
    in = strings.Replace(in, ".", "", 1)
    in += strings.Repeat("0", missingZerosUntilCents)
    out, ok := big.NewInt(0).SetString(in, 10)
    if !ok {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("could not parse '%s' as an interger", in))
    }
    return out
}
```

Is there a standard library function or other common way to parse currencies in Go? An external library is not an option.

PS: I'm parsing [Nano cryptocurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nano_(cryptocurrency)) values, which have 30 decimal places and a maximum value of 133,248,297.0. That's why I'm asking for `*big.Int` and not `uint64`.

Comment: Your postscript really throws a wrench in the works - typical currencies are fixed-precision, which is the reason why integer math works well; cryptocurrencies are not fixed precision, so no int, big or otherwise, is going to be effective for representing those values. The easiest way to handle fixed-precision currencies with the type of data you're getting would be to parse as float, multiply by 100, and convert to int. Normally you get fixed-precision inputs (so 3.1 would never appear, it would be 3.10) where you could remove the `.` and parse as int.

Comment: All cryptocurrencies I know are fixed precision. For example: The smallest fraction of a Bitcoin is one satoshi, which is 0.00000001 BTC.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Float.SetPrec

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I have already tried setting the precision to 128 bits, but did not get precise results. Maybe I used it wrongly. Could you write a full answer with a code example?

Comment: I could, but you would also need to provide a better example because currently you're asking how to parse numbers with 2 decimal places, for which default precision should work fine.

Comment: I have updated the postscript of my question. If you explain in your answer, how you choose the precision of the *big.Float values, I'll be able to adapt your answer, even if it was written for 2 decimal places.

Comment: Please provide specific examples of the source data you're trying to parse including the expected result.  It would also help if you  show any of your own attempts and describe why the result is not correct according to your expectations.

Comment: Now that I tried to replicate the problem, everything worked. I must have made a mistake in my previous implementation. I created an answer with working code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Seems like this solution is still buggy, because an inaccurate result is reported after multiplication: https://play.golang.org/p/RS-DC6SeRwz

---

After revisiting the solution with `*big.Float`, I realized, that it does work perfectly fine. I think I forgot to use `SetPrec` on `rawPerNano` previously. I'm going to provide an example for the Nano cryptocurrency, because it requires many decimal places.

This works as expected ([Go Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/aBgU1qH58DM)):

```
func nanoToRaw(in string) *big.Int {
    f, _ := big.NewFloat(0).SetPrec(128).SetString(in)
    rawPerNano, _ := big.NewFloat(0).SetPrec(128).SetString("1000000000000000000000000000000")
    f.Mul(f, rawPerNano)
    i, _ := f.Int(big.NewInt(0))
    return i
}
```

Thanks @hymns-for-disco for nudging me in the right direction!